# How can I replace the text in this field?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have looked at answers to similar questions, but I still can't see why this code will not work:

```js
function checkFname() {
  var fName = document.getElementById("firstName");
  var fnValue = fName.value;
  fnValue = fnValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + fnValue.slice(1);
  fName.innerHTML = fnValue;
  fName.style.backgroundColor = ((fnValue == "") ? "LightPink" : "#B0FFB0");
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <label for="firstName"> First Name<span>*</span></label>
  <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" onBlur="checkFname()" />
</div>
```

The function is called using `onBlur` in the field definition. `fnValue` gets capitalized correctly (evidenced by an alert box).  The colour change in the field works fine if I leave the field blank.

It just doesn't want to replace the "all lower case" input with the capitalized version.

I have also tried `document.getElementById("firstName").innerHTML` in place of `fName.innerHTML` in the penultimate line above, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Are you trying to change <input>'s innerHTML?

Answer (score 1):

Change `fName.innerHTML = fnValue;` to `fName.value = fnValue;`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to update the `value` of the input instead of the `innerHTML`.

```
function checkFname() {
  var fName = document.getElementById("firstName");
  var fnValue = fName.value;
  fnValue = fnValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + fnValue.slice(1);
  fName.value = fnValue; // the change is here
  fName.style.backgroundColor = ((fnValue == "") ? "LightPink" : "#B0FFB0");
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I knew it would be simple!